# Exremely slow Android Studio debugging after update to 6.0.1 (Note 4)

Tags: android, android-studio, galaxy

My Samsung Galaxy Note 4 received an OTA update to 6.0.1. I have Android Studio 2.2.3. Before the update my debugging speed was OK. Now it is about 100 times slower, and pretty much unuseable - it takes literally minutes to hit a breakpoint. Nothing else changed in my environment as far as I know, other than the update to 6.0.1. What can I do to get normal debugging speed back?

Comment: What version of Android was on the device before the update?

Comment: It was version 5.1.1 before the update. I have AT&T (US).

Answer (score 0):

Check if you have not added any method breakpoint. That's usually the main reason behind the significant slowness of the debugging speed.
Follow the few steps below if that the case:

1. Go to the debugger and select view breakpoints
2. Make sure the Java method Breakpoint is unchecked.

[image]